# Pack external data did not work?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, append

on my project I've used some textures and now I have to render it but on another computer.
Since I used a lot of textures, I packed them in my file (or at least I thought I did it) by choosing *File->External Data->Pack all into .blend* .
Blender told me that 31 objects where packed, but when I moved the file in the another computer the texture are not showing (they're pink as if they were missing).
Which step did I miss?
Also, I have some objects that I appended from another file (not linked); do I need the original file to show them in my .blend or since they are copies I don't need that?

EDIT: ok, strange thing. Now if I go into texture mode the texture are shown, but if I go into render mode they are all pink. What's happening?

Comment: It works for me, on 2.76, but I tried something simple. Which blender version are you using, and on which platform (windows, linux, OSX, etc)?

Comment: @m.ardito I'm using Blender 2.73 on windows 8.1

Comment: I have a 2.73 on win7, I just tried and it works... weird. Of course, you have to save the file again, after using "pack all" command... but I'm sure you did. Could it be that the .blend is read-only when you open it and try to pack all? to pack textures, you need to be able to modify that blend...

Comment: How can I check if the blend file is read-only? Anyway, I've edited the question because now it's getting weirder... in texture mode they are shown but not in render mode. How it is possible?

Comment: Ok, pack is working, at least: is the object that should have textures completely pink, or it show the textures but they are mostly pink?

Comment: The objects are completely pink, as if they are not textured...

Comment: Maybe there is something with the paths? Should I change them to relative/absolute? Or that doesn't count?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31134/discussion-between-m-ardito-and-marina-cooper).